# Why use Property Let, Get, Set instead of subroutines?

Tags: vba

My question is this:  why would I use a `Property Get`, `Property Let`, and `Property Set` in a vba class instead of a subroutine call.  For instance if I have a class `PersonCls` with a variables:

```
Private name as String
Private age as Integer
```

What is the advantage of using the property syntax over something like this:

```
Public Sub Setname(nm as String)
    name = nm
End Sub

Public Function Getname() as String
    Getname = name
End Function
```

I've looked around and have not seen this explained very well (see [VBA: Why Use Properties Instead of Subroutines or Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497575/vba-why-use-properties-instead-of-subroutines-or-functions)).  Thanks in advance.

Comment: because you can have get/let(set) properties with the same name: `Public Let Name(nm as String)` and `Public Get Name() as String`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's much simpler and more readable to write

```
myPerson.Name = myPerson.Name & " Jr."
```

As opposed to

```
myPerson.SetName(myPerson.GetName() & " Jr.")
```