# What is the difference between using Property and Sub/Function?

Tags: vba, class

Let's say there is a class variable:

```vb
Private bookName as String
```

What is the difference between the Getter and Setter writting by

```vb
Public Property Get bName() As String
    bName = bookName
End Property
```

```vb
Public Property Let bName(str As String)
    bookName = str
End Property
```

and

```vb
Public Function getbookName() As String
    getbookName = bookName
End Function
```

```vb
Public Sub setbookName(str As String)
    bookName = str
End Sub
```

I only know that Property enable Function Overload..

Comment: Uh... welcome to VBA, where function overloading is literally not a thing.  If you want to overload a property like `Value`, as in `Value As String`, `Value As Long`, `Value As Date` ... then you can't.  You can mimic overloading by using the `Variant` datatype and evaluating it yourself.  As for your question, they are practically the same.  Here is more on it: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497575/vba-why-use-properties-instead-of-subroutines-or-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497575/vba-why-use-properties-instead-of-subroutines-or-functions)

Comment: Yeah I have saw that, but is that any strong reason to let people use `Property` instead of `Sub` `Function`? (e.g. "It is not appropriate to use `Sub` `Function` for getter & setter as it is there may be some problem" or "One of them is slower" etc.)

Comment: If you were to ask me (I think you did) I would say that question is very easy to test with `Timer` and a few hundred thousand iterations of each.  For most practical applications it's probably nothing more than a semantic argument based on opinion - but I am far from being a good authority on the subject.

Comment: Well, in the one case it would show in Intellisense as a property - `Class.bookname = str` and in the other it would be a method - `Class.setBookname(str)` If one were a "purist", it would be "wrong" to set a property using a method - methods are for actions. But that's a matter of opinion; I don't think it makes any difference to ***VBA***. (It would to C#, however.)

Comment: I see..thanks for your comments!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA: Why Use Properties Instead of Subroutines or Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497575/vba-why-use-properties-instead-of-subroutines-or-functions)