# ASP.net get content page to change master page control

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

**Master page:**

```
<form runat="server">
<Scirra:MainMenu runat="server" ID="MainMenu" TopTabSelected="home" SubTabSelected="link2" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">
snip
```

**Content page:**

```
Master.MainMenu.TopTabSelected = "forum";
```

I know I'm probably doing this wrong, but is this possible?  I want to change a parameter of that control.  It says `'inaccessible due to protection level'`.

Comment: [sorry, just saw the property in the markup, ignore previous] But still try `var mainmenu = Master.FindControl("MainMenu") as MainMenu; if(mainmenu!=null)mainmenu.TopTabSelected="forum";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide a public property f.e `MenuTabSelected` in your MasterPage that Gets/Sets this property of your Menu.

```
public string MenuTabSelected {
    get { return MainMenu.TopTabSelected; }
    set { MainMenu.TopTabSelected = value; }
}
```

Then you can access it in this way:

```
((YourMasterPage)Master).MenuTabSelected = "forum";
```

where `YourMasterPage` is the type of your MasterPage.

The compiler error is thrown because you want to access a private or protected control from outside of your MasterPage-Class. This would only be allowed if it would be public, what [is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957700/public-accessor-net/1957724#1957724). You have more control if you do it the way i suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

find menu items in content page and change its value

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


Menu mainMenu = (Menu)Page.Master.FindControl("NavigationMenu");

MenuItem menuMaterials = mainMenu.FindItem("Materials");

    if (menuMaterials.Value == "Materials")
    {
         menuMaterials.Value = "NO materials";
        menuMaterials.Text = "No materials";
    }

}
```